# .scrollTop, not working on android

Tags: android, jquery, scrolltop

I have a long page with a position:fixed link. When a user clicks this link the browser scrolls to the top.

However, this doesn't seem to work on some devices using Android 4.0, like the Galaxy Pocket+.

This is the script:

```
    $(".jsrs-go-top").click(function () {
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 });
    });
```

Does anyone have a clue as to how we can solve this bug?

thx,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("body, html").scrollTop(0);
```

If need animation:

```
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop:0}, '500', 'swing', function() { 
   alert("Finished animating");
});
```